# Do composite primary key attributes have to be unique?

Tags: mysql, sql, composite-primary-key

Let's say that we create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    a integer,
    b integer,
    c integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (a, c)
);
```

Obviously the compination of a and c has to be unique. But do a and c have to be unique themselves?

Comment: No. Only the combination has to be unique to qualify as a key.

Comment: You could test this veeeeery quickly. Did you try to insert a test and see what happened?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the meagrest of effort would reveal the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they don't have to be unique separately. Only pairs should be unique.

Example:

```
a, c
1, 3
2, 3
2, 1
2, 1  -- this will cause unique key violation

INSERT INTO example(a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(2,2,3),(2,3,1);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f924a36f0c9b04b05e4b57fa7ec136b)**